# There are two buckets A and B.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, recreational-mathematics

There are two buckets A and B. Initially A has 2 litres of water and B is empty. At every hour 1 litre of water is transferred from A to B followed by returning litre back to A from B half an hour later. The earliest A will get empty is in:
A) $1.5h$

B) $4h$

C) $3h$

D) $2h$

Comment: Welcome to MSE! Can you share what you've tried and what you're having trouble with?

Comment: according to me answer should be 2h but some one asked it will be 3 h, so I m confused ..

Comment: You should make a list of the contents of each bucket after each transfer.  Does the first transfer happen at hour 0 or hour 1?

Comment: Description:-We can transfer one litre of water from A to B every hour, so we can initiate the first transection any time between 12 PM to 1 PM and next transection after one hour of 1st transection.
As per question we have to find earliest time in which A will empty so we have to do 1st transection as soon as possible and that is 12 PM.

Comment: @ Ross Millikan can we do the first transfer at 0 hr ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are initially 2 liters. At the one hour mark we remove a liter to get 1 liter.  At 1.5 hours we add half a liter to get 1.5 liters.  At 2 hour mark we remove a liter to get 0.5 liters.  At 2.5 hour mark we add half a liter to get 1 liter.  At 3 hour mark we remove a liter to get 0 liters,  and we are finished.  Thus,  the answer is $3$ hours.  (this assumes we make the first transfer at the one hour mark instead of the zero hour mark,  and that a half liter is added only added every other half hour (I. E.  at noninteger hour points)

Comment: If we will get both the bucket as 12 PM. We can transfer one litre of water from A to B every hour, so we can initiate the first transection any time between 12 PM to 1 PM and next transection after one hour of 1st transection. As per question we have to find earliest time in which A will empty so we have to do 1st transection as soon as possible and that is 12 PM

Comment: @Nagmani Alright, you should include this in your question. If you do the first transfer immediately as your comment says everything I write above holds, you just have to subtract and hour from everything (since you don't initially wait an hour). In that case, the answer IS 2 hours. You aren't really clear on which way the problem should be interpreted, hence your confusion. You need to provide the correct interpretation.